# Why curl and apt update resolve DNS names differently?

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, curl, resolv.conf

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 WSL2. The command

```
sudo apt update
```

could not resolve all the DNS names (for example `archive.ubuntu.com`):

```sh
np@DESKTOP-LF80KK2:/mnt/c/Users/niko$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
...
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

One of the addresses giving the error was `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease`, but still `curl` for it did work:

```
np@DESKTOP-LF80KK2:/mnt/c/Users/niko$ curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease | head -n 20
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: bionic
Version: 18.04
Codename: bionic
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 23:37:48 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Bionic 18.04
MD5Sum:
 32a92a5c20f378d42dd2d2f4f28f6637        628836439 Contents-amd64
 53c6a594819b51a5755f88b45d1eff7f         37766986 Contents-arm64.gz
 cd7bf6d50403da4348ee48138eace986        585939706 Contents-ppc64el
 af42d07307c5d1398c75e28986b36509        616261664 Contents-i386
 98f43960ac7029b4948a13614038593c        584794633 Contents-armhf
 31848d4faedf11946ff1af9c281f4e6b         39528051 Contents-amd64.gz
 14acbaf3166ff5b151cbac659bf6a491         36634480 Contents-s390x.gz
  5  236k    5 13787    0     0  35260      0  0:00:06 --:--:--  0:00:06 35260
curl: (23) Failed writing body (37 != 5632)
```

Also pinging or curling `archive.ubuntu.com` did work. This would mean that the domain name `archive.ubuntu.com` is resolved into an IP address correctly.

The `etc/resolv.conf` was:

```
np@DESKTOP-LF80KK2:/mnt/c/Users/niko$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.26.96.1
```

The problem for `apt update` is solved for updating the `nameserver` in the `etc/resolv.conf` to for example `8.8.8.8`.

### Question

How can `curl` and `ping` work for `archive.ubuntu.com` while `apt update` does not?  Do they use different source for DNS nameservers?